# HTTP Status 400-Bad Request Glassfish "The request sent by the client was syntactically incorrect"

Tags: http, glassfish, 400

[error message on android application](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pLGgn.png)

After reading these QNAs:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12990717/spring-mvc-the-request-sent-by-the-client-was-syntactically-incorrect

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27929825/the-request-sent-by-the-client-was-syntactically-incorrect-bad-content-typ

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43775560/request-sent-by-the-client-is-syntatically-incorrect

https://itecnote.com/tecnote/java-400-bad-request-on-a-post-service/

I've reached a point where I can guess the headers of either the client or server is incorrect. But I am wondering if the problem is on request of client or what the server is willing to accept?

The only unusual thing here is that the HEADERS accepted by server seems troublesome.

```
content-language: [\r][\n]
```

Except that I can't find any other unusual things in headers of either client or server.

These are the request headers:

```
Connection: Keep-Alive[\r][\n]
Host: paytomerchant.example.com[\r][\n]
x-forwarded-prefix: /path/to/example[\r][\n]
x-requested-with: values[\r][\n]
x-real-ip: value[\r][\n]
x-nginx-proxy: true[\r][\n]
x-forwarded-server: traefik-blablablahhh[\r][\n]
x-forwarded-proto: https,http[\r][\n]
x-forwarded-port: 443,80[\r][\n]
x-forwarded-host: hostname1,hostname2
x-forwarded-for: IPV4_1, IPV4_2, IPV4_3[\r][\n]
upgrade-insecure-requests: 1[\r][\n]
sec-fetch-user: ?1[\r][\n]
sec-fetch-site: none[\r][\n]
sec-fetch-mode: navigate[\r][\n]
sec-fetch-dest: document[\r][\n]
accept-language: en,en-US;q=0.9[\r][\n]
accept-encoding: gzip, deflate[\r][\n]
accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,app
lication/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.9[\r][\n]
user-agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 12;
 M2007J20CG Build/SKQ1.211019.001; wv) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/4.0 Chrome/108.0.5359.128 Mobile Safari/537.36[\r][
\n]
```

These are the response headers:

```
referrer-policy: same-origin[\r][\n]
x-content-type-options: nosniff[\r][\n]
x-xss-protection: 1; mode=block[\r][\n]
x-frame-options: SAMEORIGIN[\r][\n]
content-length: 1105[\r][\n]
date: Sun, 24 Dec 2023 08:00:54 GMT[\r][\n] (Note: The time was 13:43:45 NPT but log showed that)
content-type: text/html[\r][\n]
content-language: [\r][\n]
access-control-expose-headers: Authorizatio
n,auth,Dt,Referer[\r][\n]
access-control-expose-headers: Authorizatio
n,auth,Dt,Referer[\r][\n]
access-control-allow-headers: Content-Type,
Authorization,auth,Dt,Referer[\r][\n]
access-control-allow-methods: GET, POST, DELETE, PUT, OPTIONS[\r][\n]
HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request[\r][\n]
```